# Using a GPU through USB 3.0 (for neural net training - not graphics or mining)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, usb

I have a Lenovo laptop placed inside a Lenovo "docking" station with a working USB 3.0 port. This USB 3.0 port won't achieve as high of speeds as a PCI port, but for someone who just wants to get started using a GPU for machine learning training (e.g. writing test software), that's okay.

I also have a pretty simple GPU to test with, a [GeForce GT 710](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DOFD0G8). To attach it to my computer, I am using only the USB cable and X adapter from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IMYODGS). Coming in the mail, I also have an adapter to turn a [miniPCI port into a USB 3.0 port "for a graphics card"](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Graphics-card-plus-to-laptop-miniPCI-e-TO-X16-PCIe-riser-Adapter-Via-50cm-USB/262952261832?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649), which I haven't tested yet.

I downloaded the installer for my specifications from the NVIDIA webpage. However when running them in Ubuntu, I get an error that an NVIDIA graphics card can't be found. I think this could be because I'm running it from a USB 3.0 port. I have a power adapter for the graphics card. The fan is spinning, so I know that it is on.

How can I get my system to recognize the graphics card for what it is?

I know it is possible because there are now many overpriced "eGPUs" on the market that work this way. I am definitely not going to buy an eGPU straight-up. I'd like to have a DIY version instead.

Comment: I think I am misled by the use of a USB 3.0 cable. Most of these products use the USB 3.0 *cable*, but not the USB 3.0 *port*. Even the eGPUs use a thunderbolt *port*, which is a high speed than USB 3.0 (also note that USB 3.0 is a lot slower than USB 3.1). I am still waiting for the mini-PCI product, which uses an mPCIe port on almost every laptop, as well as a USB 3.0 cable. It will test this theory.

Comment: From a manufacturing standpoint it is convenient to use these cables because they are already produced for USB 3.0 products. Copper doesn't care how fast the data speed inside it goes (not 100% true, for e.g. USB 3.0 has way more copper channels than USB 2.0, but it applies here).  Its the ports on the actual laptop that need to be faster than USB 3.0 for this to work. Likewise, USB 3.1 uses a USB 3.0 *CABLE*, but the *port* on the actual laptop is faster.

Comment: same with mini PCIe, which most laptops have. All other types of PCI ports generally arent available on laptops so dont get them confused. The ExpressCard port (but not "express card") may also be a port on your laptop that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above are correct. It works using this [adapter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Graphics-card-plus-to-laptop-miniPCI-e-TO-X16-PCIe-riser-Adapter-Via-50cm-USB/262952261832?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649).

- You can use a GPU through a miniPCI with the adapter above. Most laptops have a spare miniPCI
- You can't necessarily use a GPU through any old USB 3.0 port
- You may be able to use a GPU through a USB 3.1 port. This might be called a Thunderbolt port.
- Just because an adapter uses a USB 3.0 cable, doesn't mean that it is compatible with USB 3.0. It may simply be using the cable for data transfer, but not as a USB 3.0 standard protocol.

I was able to get my NVIDIA graphics card to appear with the `lspci` command.